# How pass arrayList of Servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with information of the Data Base. Is an ArrayList of "Formulario".

Struct:

```
public class Formulario {
String titulo;
Date fecha;
int numIntegrantes;

public Formulario(String titulo, Date fecha, int numIntegrantes) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.numIntegrantes = numIntegrantes;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public int getNumIntegrantes() {
    return numIntegrantes;
}

public void setNumIntegrantes(int numIntegrantes) {
    this.numIntegrantes = numIntegrantes;
}

}
```

In the Servlet, I have:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
//...code...
ArrayList<Formulario> formularios = f.consultarFormularios();
request.getSession().setAttribute("formularios", formularios); 
request.getRequestDispatcher("datos.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

In JSP, I have:

```
<c:forEach var = "lista" items = "${sessionScope.formularios}">
  Título: ${lista.titulo} <br/>
  Número de involucrados: ${lista.numIntegrantes}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

I import JSTL to Project.
Thanks

Comment: JSP code:                                                                                          <c:forEach var = "lista" items = "${sessionScope.formularios}">              
          Título: ${lista.titulo} <br/>
          Número de involucrados: ${lista.numIntegrantes}<br/>
        </c:forEach>

Comment: Please post this comment in your post itself.

Comment: Why are you putting `formularios` in the session scope? It should be in request scope.